"Égrainer à la fourchette" vs. "Égrainer avec la fourchette"
Do we say "Égrainer à la fourchette" or "Égrainer avec la fourchette"? Or are they  both ok?
Examples:


Pour éviter les grumeaux, égrainer à la fourchette votre semoule.
Pour éviter les grumeaux, égrainer votre semoule avec la fourchette.



Non, clairement, si on égraine avec la fourchette, des grumeaux peuvent se former. Il faut égrainer à la fourchette absolument, ce qui est très différent.

@Frank Fais-en une réponse plutôt qu'un commentaire comme ça, je pourrai te downvoter ! :-)

@jlliagre Tu pourraiS, mais tu ne pourras pas, car tout ce sarcasme n'aurait pas sa place dans une vraie réponse ;-)

@Frank Dommage, je ne downvote plus beaucoup ces derniers temps, ce n'est pas que ça me manque mais... ;-) Sinon, c'était bien un futur simple pour moi mais puisque tu ne veux pas le faire, je pense que je vais répondre. N'hésite pas à me downvoter !

@jlliagre Je pourrai t'upvoter.

@Frank Tu pourrais ;-)

@jlliagre Trop de fun, je vais visiter une autre question ;-)

@Frank … un véritable feu d'artifice pour fêter les 150238 points du grand Manitou :-)

"Egrainer avec la fourchette" sonne un peu étrange. "...avec une fourchette" serait plus naturel.

@XouDo thanks yes I copy-pasted too quickly, meant "Égrainer à la fourchette" vs. "Égrainer avec une fourchette".

They are both ok although I'd rather say in the second case égrainer avec une fourchette because there is more than one fork in a kitchen.
Otherwise, the style is in my opinion "better" with égrainer à la fourchette which sounds a little like an "art" than with égrainer avec une fourchette which is more like a dull description.
Note that this verb has two spellings and pronunciations: égrainer and égrener.

L'autre jour, j'ai vu les verbes comme jeter et crocheter qui redoublent le t à certains temps, alors qu'il y a d'autres verbes qui changent le e en è à la place de reboubler le t. Plutôt que de simplifier des racines grecques utiles, une réforme de l'orthographe aurait dû simplifier ça :-)

@Frank C'est vrai, j'en profite pour dire que j'ai un bon coup de fourchète !
